# Watching a Directory for Changes Java.nio.file

Tags: java, file, watchservice

I know `java.nio.file` could provide ways to watch file's change like new file ,modify and delete . but now I wonder if there's a way to watch if the directory is being entered or one file being opened by some app like a editor.

I've read the API docs, and could find no way to achieve this. Can anyone give a clue about this, maybe other API doc rather than `java.nio.file` which could provide a way to work around this.

Comment: `I know java.nio.file could provide ways to watch file's change like new file ,modify and delete` if I'm not mistaken a directory should be fairly similar to a file. It's just a file that lists its contents. If you want it recursively it may be a little more difficult

Comment: i know directory is a file, "recursively" could be a later consideration . now i just wanna know if there a way to watch the event like a enter in a directory or the open of a file . :D

Answer (score 1):

Check out http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/WatchService.html

As for what you can watch for, check out http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/StandardWatchEventKinds.html

It doesn't look like it supports things like "a file being opened" or "someone entering the directory" which you indicated in your other comment.

Here's a sample of a simple watcher:

```
package com.stackoverflow.answers;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.FileSystems;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.StandardWatchEventKinds;
import java.nio.file.WatchEvent;
import java.nio.file.WatchKey;
import java.nio.file.WatchService;

public class FolderWatcher {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        WatchService watcher = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService();
        Path dir = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath("c:/Temp");
        dir.register(watcher, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_MODIFY, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_DELETE);
        // ...

        for (;;) {
            WatchKey key = watcher.take();
            for (WatchEvent<?> event : key.pollEvents()) {
                System.out.println("Got event: " + event.kind());
                if (event.kind() == StandardWatchEventKinds.OVERFLOW) continue;

                System.out.println("File: " + ((WatchEvent<Path>)event).context());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For more complete processing check out this tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html

Comment: i've read the docs . yes , i can't find any solution from it . and i hope someone could tell me other ways to achieve this .